# How to avoid re-sending data on refresh in Node.js with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

First of all, I want to apologyze for my english.

I have a Node.js aplication using Express and Jade. My main page has a form, wich allows people to register. I send the data via POST. I have a handler like this:

```
app.post('/userCreate', user.create);
```

And:

```
exports.create = function(req, res){
  //creates the user in the database
  res.render('./game/main');  //goes to the main game page
}
```

My problem is that when people registers, and I render the main page, in the URL appears "localhost:3000/userCreate". So, if I press F5, all data is sended again via POST, because it's catching '/userCreate' again, and it tries to create another User.

I think an option could be change the URL after creating a user, but I realized that neither 'render' nor 'redirect' methods changes it.

I've been reading about post-redirect-get pattern, but I don't know how to do a get without a form, I mean, via javascript instead of HTML.

Comment: What is your database ?
I'm supposing mongo with mongoose.
Your should maybe add an unique key for your user (for email or pseudo...) `email: { type : String, index: { unique: true }}, `

Comment: I have a unique key. Although you press F5, the user is not created cause it's Unique. But the problem it's I don't want to resend the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
res.render('./game/main');  //goes to the main game page
```

You don't actually "go" to the main game page, but rather render that view for the current url. Instead you should redirect the browser to another route:

```
res.redirect('/game'); // Or whatever url you have
```

and create a separate route for that url:

```
app.get('/game', game.index);
```

and let that route render the game:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render('./game/main');
};
```

Now `f5` will reload the game page instead of the form POST. Even if you want to use the same url as the form is on you should redirect to the GET-route of the same url, to prevent reposts.

Comment: So, are you saying that redirect does a get?

Comment: Yes. When you redirect the browser, the browser _always_ does a GET.